# Figura desenhada em canvas não está aparecendo

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Fiz o código abaixo para criar uma canvas que desenha em seu espaço um retângulo vermelho. Porém, nada aparece. Não encontro nenhum erro de sintaxe. Estou usando o Google Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p> Antes da Canvas </p>
<canvas width="120" height="60"></canvas>
<p> Depois da canvas </p>

<script>
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect = (10, 10, 100, 50);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mais uma pergunta abandonada. Não abandone perguntas pq vc pode ficar com uma imagem ruim na comunidade.

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe do `fillRect` está incorreta, deveria ser:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 50);
```

```html
<p> Antes da Canvas </p>
<canvas width="120" height="60"></canvas>
<p> Depois da canvas </p>
```

Você deve passar as propriedades no método por parâmetros (*x, y, width, height*) e não por valor de atribuição `=`.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Assim como no Java. valeu

Comment: Continua não funcionando. Esse computador é antigo,mas não pode ser falta de suporte ao html5 também né.

Comment: Soh funciona em navegadores com suporte ao html5. Mas o problema era a sintaxe mesmo.

Comment: Pois é,  mas aqui não funciona. Sabe como eu verifico se tem suporte ao html5?

Comment: É só instalar a última versão do navegador... eles tem suporte... mas entra neste site que mostra: https://html5test.com/